# iscroll links opening a new safari window?

Tags: iscroll4

I'm using iscroll because of its great features of fixed header/footer.

I have links in the footer. When in normal safari, it all works fine. When the webapp is saved to the home screen, and then launched, after a link is clicked they close the webapp and launch safari.

I've tried AJAX with no good luck.

Can someone please help.

Comment: What is `iscroll`? add some context to your question so it is easier to look for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't due to iScroll, it's the same behavior in all web apps in full screen mode. Can easily be solved with this script. It's minified, and I don't remember where the original source is, but it works great. I believe it changes href's to onclick's.

```
<script type="text/javascript">(function(a,b,c){if(c in b&&b[c]){var d,e=a.location,f=/^(a|html)$/i;a.addEventListener("click",function(a){d=a.target;while(!f.test(d.nodeName))d=d.parentNode;"href"in d&&(d.href.indexOf("http")||~d.href.indexOf(e.host))&&(a.preventDefault(),e.href=d.href)},!1)}})(document,window.navigator,"standalone")
```